# If $a^n=b^n$ with $n>1$ in a free group, then $a=b.$

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Edit : the free group 
consists of all reduced words that can be built from members of 
and formal inverses of members of .
Prove:

> If $a^n=b^n$ with $n>1$ in a free group, then $a=b.$

**My solution :**

(a) $a^n=b^n$; both sides are multiplied (left side) by $a^{-n}$, then $a^{-n}a^n = 1 = a^{-n}b^n = (a^{-1}b)^n$

$a^{-1}b=1 \implies a=b$ since we know that non identity element is of non finite  order.

I'd be grateful for your feedback!

Comment: Free groups are not commutative. $a^{-n}b^n = (a^{-1}b)^n$ requires commutativity or some other additional identity to be satisfied. Since free groups do not satisfy any additional identity, that is false unless $n=1$ or $0$.

Comment: There are multiple ways of defining a free group. Because of that, you need to tells us exactly what a "free group" is for you: how it is defined, or constructed, or what defining properties you know. Without that information, it is impossible to help you fix your error.

Comment: (What does "$/\cdot$" mean, anyway?)

Comment: "/. " Probably means "both sides are multipled by ...". That is at least how I write it on paper, so I imagine it means the same.

Comment: @Kolja: Then my only comment is "Ugh; don't. Just don't."

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I agree, I myself have only used it when writing on paper/blackboard.

Comment: @Kolja: Especially in this context, where "multiply" by itself is insufficient. On *which side*? Ugh. No. Just no.

Comment: One way to argue is to use that free groups are torsion-free and that centralizers of nontrivial elements are abelian. Any group satisfying these two properties has the property $a^n=b^n$, $n\ge 1$ implies $a=b$.

Comment: Again: "both sides are multiplied by $a^{-n}$" is insufficient. In groups, it matters *on which side* you are multiplying. And it should not be put in the middle of a sequence of equalities.

Comment: Your definition is incomplete. Under your definition, a free group on $\{x\}$ would contain both $xx^{-1}$ and $x^{-1}x$ and the empty word as distinct elements. Usually one takes **reduced** words, not just words.

Comment: Thank you! fixed it.

Comment: For a hint to get you started on a correct solution: try computing the cube of $xyxy^{-1}xy^{-1}x^{-1}$ in the free group over $\{ x, y \}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually one defines a free group on $S$ as the set of **reduced words** (not just "words") on the elements of $S$ (and perhaps also "and their formal inverses", depending on exactly how you define "word").

The claim that $a^{-n}b^n = (a^{-1}b)^n$ is not just wrong, it is *very* wrong. For $n\notin\{0,1\}$. that assertion requires normally requires $a^{-1}$ and $b$ to commute. In a free group, this will not generally happen. For example, if $S=\{x,y\}$, does $(x^{-1}y)^2$ equal $x^{-2}y^2$? No. The first one is $x^{-1}yx^{-1}y$, the second one is $x^{-1}x^{-1}yy$; these are different reduced words, and therefore are distinct elements of the free group on $S$.

So your approach is doomed.

Since your definition of free group is as sets of reduced words, you will probably want to express $a$ and $b$ as reduced words. I recommend expressing them in the form $w_1w_2w_1^{-1}$, where $w_1$ is an arbitrary reduced word, and $w_2$ is a *cyclically reduced word* (one in which the first letter is not the inverse of the last letter). (You'll have to prove you can always do that if you don't yet know it). Then $a^n = (w_1w_2w_1^{-1})^n = w_1(w_2)^n w_1^{-1}$. Do the same with $b$, and go from there using their expressions as reduced words and using that  two reduced words are equal if and only if they are identical.

Comment: I read about cyclically reduced word I did not learnt it in my studies. If i take  $a^n =w_1(w_2)^n w_1^{-1} \text{ and } b^n =  w_3(w_4)^n w_3^{-1}  \text{ then } w_1(w_2)^n w_1^{-1}=w_3(w_4)^n w_3^{-1}$

$\text{ i do not know thay i get if i know the expressions are reduced words ("using their expressions as reduced words") and how to get from  } w_1(w_2)^n w_1^{-1}=w_3(w_4)^n w_3^{-1} \text { , the result }w_1(w_2) w_1^{-1}=w_3(w_4) w_3^{-1}.$

Comment: @erez If $w_1(w_2)^nw_1^{-1} = w_3(w_4)^nw_3^{-1}$, with both sides already reduced (which will be the case if you wrote $a$ properly as a reduced word of the form $w_1w_2w_1^{-1}$), then the first letter of $w_1$ must be the same as the first letter of $w_3$, and the last letter of $w_1^{-1}$  is the same as the last letter of $w_3^{-1}$. You can cancel them, and induce on the length of $w_1$ to conclude that you must have $w_2^n = w_3^n$. Then the first letter of $w_2$ equals the first letter of $w_3$. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: @erezPS: Please stop abusing the "text" command inside math mode (you did the same think in your original post). That's why your comment's formatting is completely messed up: the interface doesn't know how to break up a math formula that has a text box. Go out of math mode when you need to write text.

Comment: I didnt know it is problematic to use \text tag , thank you

Comment: Why we take $w2$ as a "cyclically reduced word" , why we cant take $w2$  which the first letter is the inverse of the last letter ?

Comment: @erez We take $w_2$ as cyclically reduced to make sure that if $a=w_1w_2w_1^{-1}$ is a reduced word, then $w_1(w_2^n)w_1^{-1}$ is also a reduced word.